# HTML, CSS, Python Digital Clock

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I am unsure how to approach this.

I have a server running on my Raspberry Pi 3 via Python Flask. This communicates with a HTML file and a CSS file.

I want to be able to have a clock on the HTML Web Page displaying the current time and date and constantly update it. I have done this already (code shown later).

The main dilemma I am having is I want the clock to be on the web page and update BUT **I need to be able to read the HTML time USING PYTHON and execute some code based on the time from that HTML Web Page. So how would I go about doing that?** Would this require needed to pass variables from HTML to Python? Thank You

Code for clock which updates (IN HTML FILE):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>

<!-- Reference to code for clock: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock -->
```

Comment: I seriously can't even read this with all the random **bold** text every 2 words... sorry

Comment: Sorry, I've changed it, hopefully it is readable and understandable

Comment: Much better :) I don't know exactly what kind of code you want to implement, but using python to communicate time to HTML seems very inefficient... there are very good javascript snippets that do just that, locally for each user, without the server

Comment: You could use WebSockets for a biderectional communication that you can trigger from Python. However, this looks like a XY problem, where you should give more thoughts into what you want to achieve and if there are more efficient ways to achieve it.

Comment: Basically, I have a live updating clock on my web page, and within Python I want to be able to run a condition like "If Hours == 5 and Minutes = 00" then execute this code.... I can do the condition part, just being able to read HTML Variables From Python is the problem, or as Ofer Sadan mentioned there may be more sufficient ways...

Answer (score 0):

You could use php. Use a form in your html and write the time [value of the input field] out to a text file using php, and then read the contents of the output file using python.

Your `.py` file would look something like this (ideally your time variable would be one variable, hours, seconds etc concatenated, but you may have more so I've put in a loop)

```
from time import sleep

def read():
    timevars = ['your variables here']
    while True:
        file=open("timedata.txt","r")
        data = file.read()
        for i in range(len(timevars)):
            if data == inlist[i]:
                print(data)
                file=open("timedata.txt","w")
                file.write("")
        file.close()
        sleep(0.01)     
read() #you will be able to see the vars in the python file now, but you 
       #need to adjust so it only prints out the most recent value
```

php would be basic enough - just open the file, just a write-out e.g.

```
    <?php 
    $name = $_POST['writetime'];
    $fptime = fopen("timedata.txt", "w");
    fwrite($fptime, "");
    $savestring = $name;
    fwrite($fptime, $savestring);
    fclose($fptime);
    ?>
```

Comment: course, you could always just bypass the html and use just use javscript..